# Instructions for Identify-This-X questions should include title advice

Tags: support, status-completed, identify

Many [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) questions have awful titles like:

- can't remember the name of this movie
- a movie I only saw the trailer
- unknown movie from years ago

The [on topic section](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the help centre includes suggestions for identify-this questions but doesn't mention the title. I think explicit instructions to **include** key identifying details (description of a character, setting or plot) and **exclude** waffling about not knowing the name of the movie would make these questions better.

Alternatively, I can work my way up to 2000 rep editing the atrocious titles the tag currently attracts. :-)

Comment: Do you still see the help-center lacking in this regard?

Comment: it's better now for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a sentence about the titles of identification questions to the relevant section of the help center:

> Also try to give the question a meaningful title that already includes key identifying details (e.g. description of a character, setting or plot) and avoid generic titles like "name of horror movie".